# WCF net.tcp binding service consume

Tags: wcf

I have following WCF Client code to consume WCF Service :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IService1 vService;
            NetTcpBinding b = new NetTcpBinding();
            b.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
            b.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Windows;

            EndpointAddress vEndPoint = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://115.127.1.226/myservice/");
            ChannelFactory<IService1> cf = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(b, vEndPoint);

            vService = cf.CreateChannel();
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Result from the system " + vService.HellowWorld());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error Occured while connection establish to " + vEndPoint.Uri.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
```

When i run it locally it run successfully.
But When i try to consume my WCF Service remotely it Occurred a exception any one suggest 
me how can i solve this problem?

My Exception message is :

```
Could not connect to net.tcp://115.127.1.226/myservice/. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:21.0282028. TCP error code 10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
115.127.1.226:808.
```

Answer (score -1):

try to use
 ServiceBusEnvironment.SystemConnectivity.Mode = ConnectivityMode.Http;